# Re-select selected dropdown box item with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown box on a page indicating the region the article on that page is about. The region is active by means of selected in the dropdown box.

What I want is that that the item can be selected again on that page. I would like to see this happen with jquery.

Do you know how this is to be done?

Comment: pls include code you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an item in a `select` element by doing one of these:

```
$('#article')[0].selectedIndex = 3;
$('#article').attr('selectedIndex', 3);
$('#article').prop('selectedIndex', 3);
```

Depends on a version of jQuery that you're using.

If you want to operate on values rather than indexes you can do something like this:

```
// sets selected index of a select box to the option with the value "0"
$("#article").val('0'); 

// sets selected index of a select box to the option with the value ""
$("#article").val('');
```